# nohup nice job aborted when disconnected

Tags: linux, ssh, nohup

I've learned that the `nohup` command allows the command to keep running if you lose your connection or need to logout. 
I'm running `nohup nice my command &` in remoter through ssh, and after my laptop lost its network connection, the terminal says "broken pipe" and exits automatically. When I got reconnected, the job is missing. Why is it like this? Is it possible to run it from where it's left off?

Answer (score 5):

There's a few things to understand here:

1. `nohup` doesn't necessarily keep the program from losing the connection. What it does is mask the `HUP` signal, which is what the OS will send it (actually, the controlling shell) when you log off. If your program still has file descriptors connected to the terminal, it will get stopped and possibly killed. To prevent that from happening, nohup normally redirects stdout and stderr to `nohup.out` and closes stdin. But if your program may try to open file descriptors to the terminal anyway.
2. The shell doesn't keep track of "jobs" across invocations / sessions. There is no way to re-attach a job to a shell that has been exited. There are several work-arounds:

   1. Use a terminal emulator such as `screen` or `tmux` which can be re-attached to a different terminal. Here, you don't need to run your job in the background at all; just run it in the foreground and detach (`Ctrl-A d` with `screen`).
   2. Keep track of the PID of the job that was started. You can get this information with the `jobs -l` command after it has started. When you want the new shell to wait for the job, and you know the job's pid, you can issue the command:

      ```
      wait <pid>
      ```

But output will still be sent to `nohup.out`, and your only clue that it has finished is that you see a command prompt again.

Comment: Thank you. In this case I can not start from where it's left off?

Comment: If the job is still running, you should be able to find it with `ps`. If there is output, you will find it in the file `$HOME/nohup.out`.  However, if it was killed by logging out, then no.

Comment: ps shows the program is still running. Once I connected the shell, the program started to run automatically. Good point to know. Thank you for suggesting "ps".

Comment: No, the program was running _all the time_ even after you logged off. When you connected to the shell, you were connected to a _new_ session. So something like `ps -U $USER -xo pid,tty,cputime,start_time,comm`. It should list all your processes owned by you, along with the tty, the amount of time the CPU has been active on it, and the time it's been running in human terms. For your program, there should be no tty (`?`) and if it's CPU intensive, the two time counters will be roughly the same.